# Create and Get the New ID from DB but not commited yet CodeIgniter

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, commit, autocommit

In CodeIgniter,

is it possible to create transaction *(not committed yet)* and get the **ID**, and make **if statement**, if the statement is **true**, then it will be **committed**?

different function can get the same transaction?

for example:

```
$newID = $this->model->create();

if(!empty($newID)) {
      $this->model->commit();
}else{
     // cancel commit;
}
```

Comment: Did you look at codeigniter transaction? http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/transactions.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Josua you can do this things inside your model, instead of calling models from your controller.

**table structure**

[image]

**controller**

```
function index(){
    $this->load->model('mtest');
    $this->mtest->do_your_transaction();
}
```

model **mtest.php**

```
class mtest extends CI_Model
{
   function do_your_transaction()
   {
       $this->db->trans_start();
       $id = $this->insert_query();
       $this->update_query_using($id);
       $this->db->trans_complete();

       if($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE ) {
        // do something falsy
       }
       else { /* do something if true. */   }
   }

   function insert_query()
   {
       $this->db->insert('tbl', array('name1' => "hoho", 'name2' => "yohoho", "count"=>0));
       return $this->db->insert_id(); /* return last inserted. */
   }

   function update_query_using($id)
   {
       $this->db->where('id', $id)->update('tbl', array("count" => 100));
   }
} // end of mtest class
```

*if you try to execute this twice, it will only insert the first insert and update.*

Answer (score 1):

What you can try is **Running Transactions Manually**.

**Can follow as:**

```
$this->db->trans_begin();

$this->db->query('AN SQL QUERY...');
$this->db->query('ANOTHER QUERY...');
$this->db->query('AND YET ANOTHER QUERY...');

if ($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE)
{
    $this->db->trans_rollback();
}
else
{
    $this->db->trans_commit();
}
```

Read **[docs](https://ellislab.com/codeIgniter/user-guide/database/transactions.html)** for more info.

Comment: yea but in different function, still can?